# Jacob : calling vb function in Excel file without invoking "Open" statement

Tags: java, excel, jacob, vba

I'm using Jacob to call a VB function that resides in a Macro in an Excel file.

Here is my code  : [I pass the file and the vb function name as paramaters to the below java method]

```
private static void callExcelMacro(File file, String macroName) {
    ComThread.InitSTA();

    final ActiveXComponent excel = new ActiveXComponent("Excel.Application");

    try {
        // This will open the excel if the property is set to true
        excel.setProperty("Visible", new Variant(false));


        final Dispatch workbooks = excel.getProperty("Workbooks").getDispatch();
        //String    eventSink = null ;
        int id = Dispatch.get(workbooks, "Count").getInt();
        System.out.println("le nbre" + id);
        Dispatch.call(workbooks, "Add");
        Dispatch workBook = Dispatch.call(workbooks, "Open", file.getAbsolutePath()).toDispatch();
        //new DispatchEvents(sourceOfEvent, eventSink, progId)

        //new DispatchEvents(workBook, w , "Excel.Application");
        //System.out.println("le résultat"+eventSink);      

        //d.safeRelease();
        Variant V1 = new Variant( file.getName() + macroName);
        // Calls the macro
        final Variant result = Dispatch.call(excel, "Run", V1);

        // Saves and closes
        //Dispatch.call(workBook, "Save");

        com.jacob.com.Variant f = new com.jacob.com.Variant(true);
        //  Dispatch.call(workBook, "Close", f);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        excel.invoke("Quit", new Variant[0]);
        ComThread.Release();
    }
}
```

The code runs fine, but my problem is that I don't want to call the instrcution

```
Dispatch workBook = Dispatch.call(workbooks, "Open", file.getAbsolutePath()).toDispatch();
```

which displays me what the default macro executes (an Interface with input fields).

Is there a way to "Run" the VB function without "Opening" the Excel file ?

Thanks.

Comment: How will the VB code "run" when the application containing the compiler (?) is not started?

Comment: My Java code will invoke VB function on the fly (by means of buttons). So normal execution is : load the excel file, run the macro and release the Object. Hope I answered to your question.

Comment: Once you open the excel and enable code you also enable any code that is embedded in or triggered by Workbook_Open, I fear you cannot have one (the script you want) without the other (Workbook_Open)

Comment: it's the Application EnableEvents property that must be set before opening the workbook to prevent any Auto_open or WOrkbook OPen events from being executed, see my answer below please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is **no way** to execute a VBA function in an Excel workbook without opening the file...

Of course, you can prevent the AUto_open macro running by disabling events on the Excel Application object.

In Excel VBA we do this like so:

```
Application.enableevents=false
```

*(frequently in conjunction with other settings like ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts)*

in Java maybe you use:

```
excel.setProperty("EnableEvents", new Variant(false));
```

I hope that *pointers* you in the right direction (lol, boom boom  !)

Philip

Comment: Thanks fro the right answer. Is there a way to disable message boxes with Jacob? excel.setProperty("DisplayAlerts", new Variant(false)); seems to not work.

Comment: maybe *excel.setProperty("DisplayAlerts", new Variant(FALSE));*

Comment: hmmm, it is working unless you get an error - are you getting an actual error message?

Comment: In my vb function that I'm calling, I am putting "Dim Msg
Msg = MsgBox("Sessi", vbInformation, "Module1")" and along with the maybe excel.setProperty("DisplayAlerts", new Variant(FALSE)); the message "Sessi" is being displayed when I run the call to my vb function. Seems like there is a difference between alerts and MsgBox.

Comment: absolutely there is, Alerts are messages from the Application, such as Workbook is ReadOnly or something. A Message box is controlled by the developer to show a dialog with a message for the user

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, is there a solution to disable Message boxes using Jacob?

Comment: Ok, do you know if there is a way to modify VB code for a function from Jacob or any other library?

Comment: Well, my project is still a Java project. So, I have to control launching procedures from my Java code. The problem is these MessageBoxes, so I have to either comment them programmatically (using Java) or disabling these Message Boxes. Any way you can think of?

Comment: the best way is to call the Excel functions you need programmatically from Java / Jacob using Automation, and forget about the procedure in Excel...