# Conditional format on Excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxl

Is that possible to do some conditional format on Excel file with JXL or Apache POI or something else?  API java Like Macro VBA for example?

```
' Mise en forme couleur pour différence
For i = 3 To fin Step 1
    Range("C" & i).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
        Formula1:="=B" & i
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

Comment: Can you describe what do you want to exactly perform on your excel file?

Comment: OK,I have several lines at the level of column B and C. I want to display a yellow Colour when the value in column B and column C are different for the same line

Answer (score 1):

so, in your target language, these are the Excel Objects you need:

1. Create an instance of `Excel.Application` in a variable like **oXlApp**
2. use the `Excel.Application` object to open your target workbook:

   - Call the **Open** method of the **oXlApp** *Workbooks* collection passing in the filename as an argument to the Open method
3. use the `Selection` property of the **oxlApp** object to return an Excel `Range` object
4. modify the `Selection` or `Range` as below:

   5. Execute a **Delete** method on the **FormatConditions** property of the **Range**
   6. Execute an **Add** command on the  **FormatConditions** property of the **Range**

      - pass in these arguments to the **Add** method:

        - Type:=xlExpression
        - Formula1:="=$B2<>$C2"
      - set this property of the first Format Condition *to set the cells color*:

        - FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 36

   '
5. Call the **Save**method on your workbook
6. Clean up calling the **Close** method on the **Workbook** then **Quit** on the **oXlApp** and *finally, RELEASE MEMORY!*

in **Excel VBA** we would do something like this:

```
activesheet.usedrange.select
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$B2<>$C2"
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
```

this will first select the used cells, then add a conditional formatting for cols b and c

Also, see this one
[StackOverFlow: Manipulate Excel from Jacob/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612316/jacob-calling-vb-function-in-excel-file-without-invoking-open-statement/15618533#15618533)

and look at the [JXL Guide](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jexcel/docs/JExcel-PGuide.html#AEN66)

Comment: Thx for your cooepration @Philip .But this code is a VB .I wont an jxl or poi API !!!

Comment: ok, so you need to still use the same object but you will do it via OLE Automation. Foe example, you create an instance of `set oXLApp= createobject("Excel.Application")` into a variable, then open the workbook object `set oWorkbook=oXlApp.workbooks.open(sFilePath)` then use the `Selection` object which is part of the Application object to return an Excel `Range` object that you can add the formatting to...

Comment: thx I try To do it now thx ,one more question Excel.appliaction this class where I find it  ..:)

Comment: it is installed on the Windows pc when you install MS Excel.

Comment: @salvador - let us know how you get on, and if my answer solved your problem please **Accept it** ...

Comment: I get 3 hours, but I did not find any example talking on Excel.Application java with all the examples are made ​​for VBA or C + +. :(I'm block damage

Comment: sorry, but sometimes you need to read the docs, and try some coding: [JXL Guide](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jexcel/docs/JExcel-PGuide.html#AEN66) - my answer is helping you with the Excel object model, it is up to you to code in JXL or Java using objects

Comment: Thx aigain @Philip ..yes I'm using jxl but this laster 0 exemple of Conditional Formatting .I will try appch apoi thx very Much